# How to verify Pendo snippet installation?

Tags: installation, verification, pendo

How to verify my Pendo snippet installation is correct, or simply see the data sent to Pendo? Preferably done in a browser's dev tool.

Answer (score 2):

From [Pendo's documentation](https://support.pendo.io/hc/en-us/articles/360046272771-Developer-s-Guide-To-Installing-the-Pendo-Snippet#VerifyingYourInstall), you can run `pendo.validateInstall()` in a browser's console. You will be able to see the data.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Google Chrome (or any web browser with dev tools).
2. Visit your domain with the Pendo snippet installed; usually it's your **http://localhost:<*InsertYourPort*>** during development.
3. <*Right Click*> -> *Inspect* -> *Console*.
4. Type `pendo.validateInstall()` as what Shao has suggested with Pendo's docs attached.
5. If problems occur, Pendo's docs has debugging tips and commands you can use.